# How to check empty file path and valid file name?

Tags: python, pandas, filenames, filepath

I am a beginner in python.  I have some problems in my learning, I hope I can find the answer here.

1. I cancel select file dialog and PyCham show file not found error.

   ```
   # importing openpyxl module
   import openpyxl as xl
   from openpyxl import Workbook
   from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
   from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
   from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle

   # importing pandas module
   import pandas as pd
   from tkinter import *
   from tkinter import CENTER
   from tkinter import ttk
   from tkinter import filedialog
   from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
   from tkinter import messagebox as msg
   from pandastable import Table
   from tkintertable import TableCanvas

   # importing get filename module
   import ntpath
   from pathlib import Path

   # importing numpy module
   import numpy as np


    def openFile():
         filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\Desktop',
                                                title='Check Duplicate',
                                                filetypes=(('Excel Files', '*.xlsx'),
                                                           ('All Files', '*.*')))    
   df = pd.read_excel(filepath)

   window = Tk()
   window.geometry('300x300')
   window.resizable(False, False)
   button_choose_file = ttk.Button(window, text='Choose File', command=openFile).pack(ipadx=50, ipady=10, expand=True)
   window.mainloop()
   ```
2. Q1: How to use `if`, `else` to check that is a empty file path with `pandas` read?
3. Q2: If my select excel filename is `Student_2020_01_05.xlsx` (Format: filename_yyyy_mm_dd.xlsx). How to  `if`, `else` to check that is valid file name?

Comment: 2) One method to check if a file exists is `os.path.isfile(path)` or `os.path.exists(path)` Both functions return a boolean value. 3) This depends (almost) entirely on what *you* consider a ‘valid’ filename.  Is there a specific convention that must be met? If not, the OS would not allow the file to be created (hopefully) with a filename is considered invalid, by standard; so you don’t need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

One method to address both questions is to write a helper function to perform the tests. If *both* tests pass, a `True` value is returned, otherwise `False` is returned.

Then, you can simply use the following statement:

```
if valid_file(fpath=filepath):
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

The file will only be read if:

1. The filepath is not `None` (the file was chosen by the user and not cancelled.)
2. The filepath exists.
3. The filename meets the required convention.

#### Helper function:

This function first perfoms a test that `fpath` is not `None` (verifying a file was selected). Then, a `True` value is returned if the **filepath** exists *and* the **filename** meets the required naming convention.

```
import re

def valid_file(fpath: str) -> bool:
    """Verify a filename is valid and path exists."""
    if fpath is None:
        return False
    re_file = re.compile('[A-Z][a-z]+_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}.xlsx')
    return os.path.exists(fpath) and re_file.match(os.path.basename(fpath)) is not None
```

---

#### Futher comments:

Here is an explanation of the regular expression (regex) pattern used to validate the file:

```
'[A-Z][a-z]+_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}.xlsx'
```

- Match a single upper case letter.
- Match one or more lower case letters.
- Match an underscore.
- Match four digits followed by an underscore.
- Match two digits followed by an underscore.
- Match two digits.
- Match '.xlsx' as the file extension.